# Faster way to lookup awk

Tags: awk, lookup

I have a list in a file as follows (in actual around 335 K):

```
      abc
      efg 
      hij
```

I want to look for the presence of this list in some files-all of which have the same extension of .count such that my output would be i.e what's the binary count of the above list in each .count file:

```
    abc 1
    efg 0
    hij 1
```

(just gives me a binary score of 1 for present and 0 for absent)
In my code I am looping through each file with extension of .count and look for binary score for above list for characters and I am looking for it as follows:

```
 awk -v lookup="$block" '$1 == lookup {count++ ; if (count > 0) exit} END {if (count) print 1 ; else print 0}' $file.count
```

The lookup is taking forever and I wonder if there is another way to expedite the lookup?

Comment: Could you maybe add some punctuation so I can make sense of your question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, this doesn't make much sense

```
{count++ ; if (count > 0) exit}
```

can you see why?

Second you can reduce the looping by loading up the lookup into an array, for example,

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} {print $1 in a}' lookupfile otherfiles*
```

will print the 1/0 digits for each line

to print the ids as well

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} {print $1, $1 in a}' lookupfile otherfiles*
```

UPDATE: fixed the typo

for your example

```
$ echo -e "abc\ndef\nghi" > lookup
$ echo ghi > file1
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} {print $1, $1 in a}' lookup file1
ghi 1
```

**UPDATE2:** enhanced example

It will be easier if the order didn't matter but this preserves the order too and can run multiple files at the same time.  You can tweak printing the header (print f)

with this setup

```
$ echo -e "abc\ndef\nghi" > lookup
$ echo ghi > file1
$ echo abc > file2
```

you can run

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;c++;next} 
   FNR==1 && f{print f;
               for(k=1;k<=c;k++) print a[k], a[k] in b; delete b}
              {b[$1]; f=FILENAME}
           END{print f; 
               for(k=1;k<=c;k++) print a[k], a[k] in b; delete b}' lookup file1 file2

file1
abc 0
def 0
ghi 1
file2
abc 1
def 0
ghi 0
```

> **Explanation**
>
> `NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;c++;next}` is for loading up the lookup table into array
>   in order (awk arrays are actually hash structures and iteration order
>   can be random) and count the number of entries.
>
> `FNR==1 && f{print f;`  at the beginning of each file after the first
>   one print the filename
>
> `for(k=1...) print a[k], a[k] in b; delete b}` iterate over the lookup
>   table in order and check the file processed before has the corresponding entry and remove the processed file values (in b)
>
> `{b[$1]; f=FILENAME}` load up the entries for each file and set the
>   filename (which will be used above to defer printing after the first
>   file)
>
> `END{print f; ...` same printing step explained above now for last
>   file.

Comment: Thanks , I somehow knew I wasn't doing it right, thanks for your input.

Comment: Also how will I print the ids of those lookup files?

Comment: I loaded a lookupfile with 
abc
efg 
hij and then put just abc in other file and executed the above command, I am getting the results as follows:  abc 0
efg 0
hij 0
abc 0 where it is aggregating the results from both files and giving 0 as the occurrence for each line

Comment: there was a typo, fixed now and added an example how to use.

Comment: I also want the rest of the components to be printed such that those not present will be assigned a 0 and those present will be assigned a 1, also could you breakdown the code so that I can write better codes by myself?

Comment: Please make up a small example like I did with one lookup file and two check files and post them all with the expected result(s) in you original question.

Comment: I am using the same files as above, my lookup file is abc
efg 
hij and my other file is abc, and I execute the command  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} {print $1, $1 in a}' lookupfile otherfile , I get abc 1 when I would want abc 1 efg 0 hij 0 like in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much @karakfa I cannot tell you how much has it improved and helped the processing time!

Comment: The file that I am looking into has the values present in 1st column however the values are in the form of column values as: ABC:abc:123; CDF: efg: 234; VCF:hij:456 , I tried using split on the column and storing the 3rd value in the array, but that didn't work.

Comment: you have to handle the spaces around the colon chars.  Perhaps you should ask a new question with the new field values...