# How can I identify lines from a delimited file, based on a lookup file in unix

Tags: unix, awk

Assume that there are two files
File1 - lookup.txt

```
CAN
USD
INR
EUR
```

Another file Input.txt

```
1~Canada~CAN
2~United States of America~USD
3~Brazil~BRL
```

Both files may be very huge, hypothetically several thousand of records . Now I'm trying to identify the records in Input.txt and identify them based on values in lookup file.

The expected output should be

```
1~Canada~CAN
2~United States of America~USD
```

I tried to do something like below

```
#!/bin/sh
 lookupFile=$1  #lookup.txt
 inputFile=$2   #input.txt
 outputFile=$3  #output.txt
 while IFS= read -r line
  do
  awk -F'~' '{if ($3==$line) print >> $outputFile}'  $inputFile
 done < "$lookupFile"
```

But I'm getting error like
`awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=input.txt FNR=2) fatal: can't redirect to`

How can I fix this issue ? Also if the files really huge, with several thousand of records to search, is this an efficient way ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Faster way to lookup awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435165/faster-way-to-lookup-awk); i.e. `awk 'BEGIN{FS="~"} NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} ($3 in a)' lookup.txt input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Will test this option with a huge data set and update back here.

Comment: @jared_mamrot, link you have given doesn't show how to set field separator with another file it only shows dealing with 2 files. Also we need not to set `~` for the first file as it has only 1 value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. We could do this in single `awk` we need to take care of setting field separator as `~` before input.txt.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} ($3 in arr)' lookup.txt FS="~" input.txt
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk '                          ##starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                       ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when lookup.txt is being read.
  arr[$0]                      ##Creating array arr with $0 as index.
  next                         ##next to skip all further statements from here.
}
($3 in arr)                    ##If $3 is present in arr then print that line.
' lookup.txt FS="~" input.txt  ##Mentioning Input_files and setting FS to ~ before input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-awk solution that you could compare with on the performance point of view:

```bash
$ grep -wFf lookup.txt input.txt
1~Canada~CAN
2~United States of America~USD
```

Warning: this does not match only on the last word. So if some values in `lookup.txt` can also be found elsewhere in `input.txt`, prefer another solution. Or, if it contains nothing that could be interpreted as a regular expression operator, preprocess `lookup.txt` before grep. Example with bash, sed and grep:

```bash
$ grep -f <( sed 's/.*/~&$/' lookup.txt ) input.txt
1~Canada~CAN
2~United States of America~USD
```